# FromBase64String Method maximum length

Tags: c#, .net

FromBase64String Method maximum length

Comment: 2,147,483,647 is the max length of a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically as long as is practical - you'll be hit by other limitations (maximum size of a string, or indeed any object) before you hit a problem in `FromBase64String` itself.

If you want to read *huge* amounts of base64 data, you'll need to split it up. So long as you read chunks which are multiples of 4 characters at a time, you should be able to transform it one chunk at a time without any problem.